# How should ownership for two closely tied data structures be designed?

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, reference, ownership

I have a class `A` and a struct `B` (it's a plain old data structure). These two model a system in the way that `A` represents, in a sense, the state of the entire system, and is composed of both multiple `B`s and other state. What this means is that `B` is arguably worthless without `A`. I want to make an API where you can "add" `B`s to an `A` and then later modify the state of the `B`s directly (by keeping something like a reference to them).

What I'm not sure about, though, is how to design this in terms of ownership. I've got a few options. This is complicated by the fact that I'm using C++. If I were using Java, I would probably design the code either like this:

```
class A {
    private List<B> bs = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(B b) {
        bs.add(b);
    }
}
```

where the user of the API creates the `B`s itself, or like this:

```
class A {
    private List<B> bs = new ArrayList<>();

    public B create(int data) {
        B b = new B(data);
        bs.add(b);
        return b;
    }
}
```

where the `A` system creates the objects itself. This is probably the better way since `B`s are nothing without an `A`. I could maybe even somehow make the `B` constructor only accessible to `A` but I'm not sure how.

But keep in mind, that is in Java. This system is to be programmed in C++, and it works differently.

I suppose the first example would look similar:

```
class A {
public:
    void add(B& b)
    {
        bs.push_back(&b);
    }

private:
    std::vector<B*> bs;
};
```

but since I preferred the second option, I tried to translate it:

```
class A {
public:
    B& create(int data)
    {
        bs.emplace_back(data);
        return bs.back();
    }

private:
    std::vector<B> bs;
};
```

but in this case, I'm returning a reference to the `B`. When `bs` is being resized, it will potentially move in memory, therefore invalidating the reference returned. How would you solve this problem? Or in what other way would you try to design this?

Comment: First, do not take a reference and store a pointer.  Make ownership and lifetime **clear**.  Who has the right to access a `B`?  How do they name it?  How long does this access last?  Can `B` outlive its `A`?  Is `B` read only data, or must it be active?  Can you make `B` immutable?  You have entire menus of options, the information given does not narrow down to one answer.  Give a less abstract description as well as your abstract one, you may not know what details are safe to abstract.

Comment: It's a rigid body physics simulation. `A` is the world which stores, among others, bodies and joints between them. `B` is a rigid body that contains information such as the body's shape, current position and velocity.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason that you can't use either data model in C++, it's just the syntax that differs.

In the first case, the caller of `add` must instantiate the instance of `B`.  It then passes B into the instance of `A`, who then holds a reference (or pointer, in C++ terms) to `b`:

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class B {
};

class A {
public:
    void add(std::shared_ptr<B> b) {
        bs.push_back(b);
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<B> > bs;
};

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    A a;
    std::shared_ptr<B> b(new B);
    a.add(b);
}
```

In this implementation, we hold shared pointers to each instance of B.  Shared pointers use a reference counter similar to how Java handles memory management.  So long as *someone* holds a reference to a specific instance of B (through a `shared_ptr`), that specific instance will remain resident in memory.  Where `shared_ptr`'s differ from Java is that **as soon as** the reference count decriments to 0, the instance is deleted.  Java waits for some point in the future to garbage collect.  This pattern is known as RAII in C++ (resource acquisition is initialization).

Your second model can be handled similarly.  You can either use `shared_ptr`s in your vectors or raw pointers directly.  Since I already showed `shared_ptr`s above, I'll show raw pointers here:

```
class B {};

class A {
public:
    ~A() {
        for (std::vector<B*>::iterator it = bs.begin(); it != bs.end(); ++it) {
            delete *it;
        }
        bs.clear();
    }

    B* create(int data) {
        B *b = new B(data);
        bs.push_back(b);
        return b;
    }

private:
    // block copy construction since we don't manually copy the contents of our
    // vector
    A(const A&) {}
    void operator=(const A&) {}
    std::vector<B*> bs;
};
```

In this design, since we used raw pointers, we must manage the memory ourself.  This introduces the need for a destructor that frees all instances of `B` stored in the vector when the instance of `A` is destroyed.  We are also now returning a pointer to each new `B` instance that we create in `create`.  This memory model is more ambiguous than in the first approach since we've got raw pointers floating around and thus need to adopt a policy, which is enforceable only through discipline, as to who owns and is responsible for the memory management of each instance of `B`.  A developer coding against this API can delete an instance of B returned to him, which will lead to segfaults or undefined behavior the next time you try to access that instance of `B`.

My recommendation? Use `shared_ptr` unless this requires bleeding fast performance and every operation counts.

**Edit**

Hid copy constructor and assignment operator per Yakk's recommendation.

Comment: So you recommend my second model with `shared_ptr`?

Comment: Either one.  I personally like the first model more because you decouple the constructor of `B` from the `add`/`create` method of `A`.  If you add new constructor arguments to `B`, you'll need to add them to the second method's `create` method too.  That being said, they are both valid.  Using `shared_ptr` will make your life easier.

Comment: Sure, but `B`s should never exist without existing in one, and only one `A`.

Comment: The first one needs a `move` and `make_shared`.  The second one should store a `std::vector` of `unique_ptr` if you are not exposing `shared_ptr`: manual `delete` is a sign of bugs.  For example, you failed to block copy construct/assign in your `A`, which would automatically happen if you had `unique_ptr`s.

Comment: @Yakk I prefer to not use c++11 because not all compilers on all systems support it at this point (I do scientific computing and must compile on my compute cluster, which is frequently running some nasty old version of Linux with antiquated compilers).

Comment: Does it change anything if I tell you that this is a mechanical simulation of rigid bodies? `A` is the world in which the bodies exist and `B` is the class of rigid bodies. The rigid bodies mean nothing without a world, yet I need to access it from outside the world to change parameters such as mass and shape.

Comment: `std::shared_ptr` is C++11, so you already failed at your preference.  And not using C++11 is not an excuse to ignore rule of 3.  You wrote a destructor, you need to handle or block copy/assign or you will encourage bad practices.

Comment: @Yakk I didn't realize that `std::shared_ptr` is C++11 since it doesn't require C++11 *language* features.  Re-read your comments and have incorporated the bare minimum in the second example.  I'm not familiar with `move` or `make_shared`, so I can't comment on their usage.  Manual delete isn't necessarily a sign of bugs, but as my first whack at the code above showed (lacking copy constructor/assignment operator hiding), it definitely leaves you more open to them.  All of these are reasons why `std::shared_ptr`s are useful if you have access to them (or `boost::shared_ptr` if you don't).

Comment: Found a good `unique_ptr` introduction article at Dr. Dobbs: http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/c11-uniqueptr/240002708.  It also covers `std::move`.